# how to run javascript statement by order

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I want to first display a message and then redirect my page:

```
toastr.success('Your report has been submitted successfully.');
window.location = '/Report';
```

But the code above allow the two statements to run at the same time. In result, redirect takes place before the toastr message is shown, which take time..

Do we have something like `$.when(...).done(...)` for this situation?

--- update ---

In case someone does not know [toastr](http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/), it is a library to display messages on a web page.

Of course set a timer will work. But is there any elegant way that we can run the second statement after the first is completed?

Comment: What does this `toastr.success(` function do? and Why do you think your script would wait in that line?

Comment: What does the success method do that takes time?

Comment: Perhaps we return a promise from toastr when the toast disappears. I havent looked into this yet, but feel free to add it to the list of feature requests on github. It would require recent versions of jquery in that case, so if there is a way I can eliminate that and get the feature in, I would consider it. But yeah, add it to the github list.

Answer (score 4):

You could use setTimeout :

```
toastr.success('Your report has been submitted successfully.');
setTimeout(function(){window.location = '/Report';}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yeah it will work, but kind of ugly. Can we let the redirect happen after `toastr.success` is completed? Arbitrarily waiting for 2000ms is definitely not a good solution.

Comment: Is this answer truly the only solution we have?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as a callback to execute after the function has completed. Please see the chosen answer on this similar question: [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of success using the toastr `onHidden` option. It's basically an event callback that allows you to set a redirect url, to be fired when the toast closes or is hidden.

```
// Notify the user of success and redirect when the toast closes
toastr.options.onHidden = function () {
     window.location.href = <YOUR REDIRECT URL>;
};

// Fire the success toast which is bound to the onHidden function                    
toastr.success('Success!<br/><br/>You\'ll now be automatically redirected to your current items.', 'Download Success', { timeOut: 3000, closeButton: true, positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right', progressBar: true });
```