# rotate with jquery then do something else

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to rotate an element with jquery and then I want to do something else when its done.
The rotate is working but why not the alert?

see jsfiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cVea/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="square">click me</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer;
```

}

JS:

```
$('.square').click(function () {
  rotate($(this), -180, 1000);
});
function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
    element.animate({ borderSpacing: degrees }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: speed
    }, function () {
        alert("I'm done");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update to this:

```
.promise().done(function () {
    alert("E");
 });
```

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cVea/7/)

---

#### Your updated function:

```
function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
    element.animate({
        borderSpacing: degrees
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: speed
    }, 'linear').promise().done(function () { // update like this
        alert("E");
    });
}
```

---

#### With use of `complete:fn` callback:

---

```
function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
    element.animate({
        borderSpacing: degrees
    }, {
        duration: speed,
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("E");
        }
    });
}
```

---

### [Demo with `complete:fn` callback](http://jsfiddle.net/6cVea/8/)

---

Comment: @mostafaznv You are welcome, glad this is somehow helped you too.

Comment: yes ... it was wonderful. can we do that through jquery queue?

Comment: well than can be used but do you have any question posted?

Comment: no ... but i have many problems with `queue` ... and it is very useful for me . i want to know how we can execute several functions through `queue`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second `function()`:

```
function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
    element.animate({ borderSpacing: degrees }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: speed
    }, 'linear');

    alert("E");
}
```

(I've also added a `;` after your `element.animate()`.)

**Edit:**

You can delay the alert with a `setTimeout()` something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert("E");
}, 1000);
```

(From the most recent answer in the question I linked to in the comments.)

Comment: This will alert at the same time as the animation, not after it's finished.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake.  I'm used to situations where the first function completes before the alert is called.  Looks like I need to do more research about synchronous and asynchronous execution (such as read this other stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other).