# Callbacks on Asynchronous Functions with SetInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, setinterval

I'm trying to get something to run after a function using setInterval is done. I'm trying to do this with callbacks but I can't seem to get it work?

So far I have the following

```
        var testing = ['A','D','F','H','B'];
        var index = 0;
        var wordCount = 1; 

        var showHide = setInterval(function () {
            var displayWords = "";
            var mx = index + wordCount;
            if (mx > testing.length) mx = testing.length;
            for (var i = index; i < mx; i++) {
                displayWords += testing[i] + " ";
            }
            d3.select("#stim").text(displayWords).style("font-size","150px");
            index = mx;
            if (index > testing.length) {
                clearInterval(showHide); 
                d3.select("#stim").text('L,R').style("font-size","150px");

            }
        }, 1000);
```

And I want the following line to execute "after":

```
d3.select("#stim").text('L,R').style("font-size","150px");
```

I tried using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other) but when I try to put "showHide" in its own function, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: execute "after" what?

Comment: @igor I want the above line for execute after showHide

Comment: are you saying that condition in `if (index > testing.length) {` is never true?

Comment: @Igor that condition allows the letters to disappear after being displayed