# Javascript trouble with callbacks to execute asynchronous calls synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

After reading this thread [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other), I am still unsure why this doesn't work and having trouble making asynch calls synchronous:

```
function testCallBack(){
    one(two);
}
function one(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){alert("delay 1")},2000);
    callback();
}
function two(){
    setTimeout(function(){alert("delay 2")},1000);
}
```

How can I make two() wait until one() completes? I still see "delay 2" before I see "delay 1".

EDIT: The above is a simplified example of what I want to do, just trying to do a hello world for callbacks. I am trying to apply it like this:

```
function add() {
    addCalendar(getCalendarID);
}
function addCalendar(callback) {
    var req = gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert(
    {
        "resource": 
        {"summary": "McGill Schedule",
            "description": "Winter 2015",
            "timezone": "Canada/Montreal"}
    });
    req.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log("added calendar");
        callback();
    });
}
function getCalendarID() {
    var req = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({});
    req.execute(function(resp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
            if (resp.items[i].summary === "McGill Schedule") {
                console.log("Mcgill Sched id: " + resp.items[i].id);
                calendarID = resp.items[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Which still doesn't seem to work even with the callback() inside the response of the api call.

Comment: What does "completes" mean to you? If you want to wait until after the `alert()`, then that `setTimeout` function is wherein you need to put the `callback()` call.

Comment: @Bergi see my edit above - when I run that I dont even see the console.log("Mcgill Sched ...") for some reason.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation for `gapi.client.calendar...`?

Comment: gapi.client is the javascript client for google apis (here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js), the calendar specific stuff is here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Comment: the documentation is pretty thin, I found most of the useful stuff on stack overflow

Comment: Are you sure it does what you think it does? Also, what is the return value - I would have thought it would be what you're trying to fetch.

Comment: The methods work individually. Return value of req.execute()? I dont believe it returns anything. I don't want a return value for getCalenderID, just want to update the global variable calendarID.

Comment: Never mind it magically starting working! I have this hosted on github pages so it might just have taken a while to update. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the callback:

```
function testCallBack(){
    one(two);
}
function one(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("delay 1");
        callback();
    },2000);
}
function two(){
    setTimeout(function(){alert("delay 2")},1000);
}
```

The point of `setTimeout` is that it is asynchronous so it wont block your code from continuing. You have the scope to call the callback from within `one`'s `setTimeout` function though.

See it working in a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z71gkpfg/)**

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I still can't seem to apply it to my google calendar api calls though.