# Javascript functions in series

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a function `first` which adds a class that causes the page to fade to `0` on clicking an anchor tag. How would I add the following...

if style = opacity "0" (in other words function one has successfully completed) add the next function. The code is given below.

They both run independently from there respective triggers but not sure how to ensure that function two runs only on completion of the first.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].addEventListener("click", first);
function first() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("content").classList.add("animation")
}

function next() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("animation");
}
```

Comment: What is happening on adding `animation` class. Is there is any css animation in it?

Comment: I'm new to coding how would I implement that, sorry if this is a really simple question.

Comment: what you want clicking on `a` tag will run function `first()` and once that is done you want to run `next()`?

Comment: Darren, have you tried JSfiddle?  Its a practice location so you can show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hint: listen for the [`transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) on the element that is doing a CSS transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("content").add('animation');
   next();
});

function next(){
 if (document.getElementById("content").contains('animation')) {
     document.getElementById("profile").classList.add('animation');
 } else {
   return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use JQuery, it is much more easier to manipulate css attributes and stuffs. And for pure javascript, I think it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other), it might not be straight answer, but it might help you out.

Use callback functions

```
function func(value, callback){
  //do stuff
  callback();
}
```

In your case

```
function first(alphavalue, second) {
    // do some stuffs
    if(alphavalue == 0) {
    // run the call back
        second();
    }else { // do no stuffs }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I agree with Gabriel. Might be easier to use jQuery. Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mqeLg445/ .

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#content").on("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", 
function(event) {
   // Do something when the transition ends
   next();
});
```

Check [transition end event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes).