# sync code in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Below is schema of my js code.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event){
data = get_data();
API=url+data;
event.waitUntil(fetch(API).then(...)
)
})
```

I want to make it synchronous code. How do I stop 'API=url+data;' from executing until get_data is not finished?

Comment: What is it - `get_data`? Are there any async actions in this function?

Comment: You don't. There is no `waitUntil` in Javascript. Embrace asynchrony.

Answer (score 0):

You may use callbacks when function is completed. Alternatively, see [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [`waitUntil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil) already, so the solution is trivial: use promises!

Let `get_data` return a promise for the asynchronous result (instead of nothing), so that you can do

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(get_data().then(data => {
    let API=url+data;
    return fetch(API);
  }).then(...));
})
```