# purpose of $q service in angular?

Tags: angularjs, q

I am not able to understand the use of `$q` service in angular js. Can some one please give elaboration on this topic that

what is the `$q` service in angularjs? How can we use that

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain the use of $q service in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495864/can-anyone-explain-the-use-of-q-service-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think article i wrote about $q might help you.

**Introduction to $q**

$q is an angular define a service. It’s same as new Promise(). But $q takes things to the next level by enhancing additional feature that developers can use to perform complex tasks more simply.

This is a sample for creating promise using $q

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$q){
  var work = "resolve";
  var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (work === "resolve") {
        resolve('response 1!');
    } else {
        reject('Oops... something went wrong');
    }
  }); 
  promise.then(function(data) {
    alert(data)  

  }) 
})
```

**$q.defer()**

`$q.defer()` return the instance of the promise constructor. Once you create a defer object there are following methods and properties that you can access from that object

`resolve(value)` – resolves the derived promise with the value. If the value is a rejection constructed via $q.reject, the promise will be rejected instead.

`reject(reason)` – rejects the derived promise with the reason. This is equivalent to resolving it with a rejection constructed via $q.reject.

`notify(value)` - provides updates on the status of the promise's execution. This may be called multiple times before the promise is either resolved or rejected.

`promise` – {Promise} – promise object associated with this deferred

**Conclusion**

Use `$q` for constructing promises from non-promise Objects/callbacks, and utilize `$q.all()` and `$q.race()` to work with existing promises.

Comment: very helpful. Thanks