# How to use $q on my 2 forEach?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, chain

I have two angular.forEach

The second one musn't start untill the first one is finished :

```
$scope.rendezVous.j_plaignant = [];

angular.forEach(data.data,function(objet){
    if(objet.idpartie==1){
        $scope.rendezVous.j_plaignant.push(objet.idjuriste);
    }
})

$scope.rendezVous.juristes_plaignant = [];

angular.forEach(data.data,function(objet){
    if(objet.idpartie==1){
        $scope.rendezVous.juristes_plaignant.push(objet);
    }
})
```

I've tried this with no luck :

```
var defer = $q.defer();
$scope.rendezVous.j_plaignant = [];

angular.forEach(data.data,function(objet){
    if(objet.idpartie==1){
        $scope.rendezVous.j_plaignant.push(objet.idjuriste);
    }
})

$q.all($scope.rendezVous.j_plaignant).then(lastTask);

function lastTask(){
    $scope.rendezVous.juristes_plaignant = [];

    angular.forEach(data.data,function(objet){
        if(objet.idpartie==1){
            console.log(objet);
            $scope.rendezVous.juristes_plaignant.push(objet);
        }
    })
}
```

It would be nice if you have an idea, $q is difficult to understand.

I don't understand why i isn't possible to add a .then after a forEach., it is so annoying, i can't understand $q.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495864/can-anyone-explain-the-use-of-q-service-in-angularjs

Comment: There is something missing from your code as the snippets shown are all synchronous. Are the two `forEach` blocks inside different `.then` blocks? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Not even clear why you need two forEach.....or what specific problem you are having

Comment: Why using `$q` is a requirement? Your first could should already do what you want, not starting the second `forEach` until the first one has finished.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a defer.

When the second `forEach` occurs, the first is done. This is synchronous.