# Synchronizing function calls with Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, synchronization

I'm trying to synchronize function calls but don't want to use callbacks. I'm still pretty new to this stuff so a little explanation is appreciated

```
var h1 = $('#title>h1');
$(window).ready(function(){
  var s1 = "WELCOME.";
  var s2= "Projects";

  print(0,s1);
  print(0,s2);
});

function print(i,st){
  setTimeout(function(){
    h1.text(st.substr(0,i));
    if(i<8){
      print(i+1,st);
    }
  },250);
}
```

I did try using Promise from here: [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other)
but didn't work out. It gave error that **result** was not found and I couldn't really figure it out.

```
var h1 = $('#title>h1');
$(window).ready(function(){
  var s1 = "WELCOME.";
  var s2= "Projects";

  new Promise(function(fulfill,reject){
    print(0,s1);
    fulfill(result);
  }).then(function(result){
    print(0,s2);
  });

});
```

This is what I got from the stackoverflow question and error that I got was:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: result is not defined
        at projects.js:8
        at new Promise ()
        at HTMLDocument. (projects.js:6)
        at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
        at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaBYQz

Comment: post the error stack

Comment: *"I did try using Promise from here..."* Show your attempt.

Comment: Post your try and the error console log.

Comment: Added the code and error

Comment: So, before Promises you need to learn about scopes and variables. Your `result` variable is really not defined.

Comment: That's what I want to understand. Where does `result` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var h1 = $('#title>h1');
$(window).ready(function() {
  var s1 = "WELCOME.";
  var s2 = "Projects";
  print(0, s1).then(()=>print(0, s2));;
});

function print(i, st, p) {
  return new Promise(done => {
    p = p || done;
    if(i > st.length) return p();
    setTimeout(function() {
      h1.text(st.substr(0, i));
      print(i + 1, st, p);
    }, 250);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=title>
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

You need to resolve the first promise that is created when you call `print` for the first time. When you call `print` recursively you're creating new promises, so if you simply call `done` when the last letter is printed you would only be resolving the last promise. So I created a new parameter that the function can use to recursively pass the first promises `done` function to the past promise.

The first time the function is called, `p` is undefined, using `p = p || done;` we are assigning the value of `p` to `done` **only** if `p` is undefined. So by the time the whole word is printed (ie, `i > st.length`) `p` will still be the very first `done` function. By calling `return p();` we resolve the first function and end execution.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit about what you did in print(). What exactly is **p** needed for?

Comment: @ShivamDhawan - I've added a slightly more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it to use promises:

```js
var h1 = $('#title>h1');

function onReady() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $(window).ready(function(){
      var s1 = "WELCOME.";
      var s2= "Projects";
      resolve([s1, s2]);
    });
  });
}

onReady().then(function(res) {
  print(0, res[0]);
  print(0, res[1]);
});


function print(i,st){
  setTimeout(function(){
    h1.text(st.substr(0,i));
    if(i<8){
      print(i+1,st);
    }
  },250);
}
```

Comment: Not working. It is showing the output for the second function call. Can you explain a bit what you were trying to do?

Comment: @ShivamDhawan I've just rewrote your code to use promise but you have to add in your question the expected output so we can help you more

Comment: What I'm trying to do is set text to h1: "WELCOME" one char at a time creating a sort of typewriter feel. And when that's done It will set that text to "Projects". I am able to get the typewriter effect but when I'm running the code It's showing me only output for "Projects".

Comment: I have added the codepen also in the description. Hope that'll help make my aim clear

Comment: Always strive to properly describe your answers, this lack clarity.

Comment: Yes, I felt that. That's why I included the codepen link.