# call a function after the setTimeout finishes execution- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I want to call the function d() after the execution of three functions a(), b(), c(), These three functions executes parallely.

```
setTimeout(function a(){ alert("Hello A"); a()}, 3000);
setTimeout(function b(){ alert("Hello B"); b()}, 3000);
setTimeout(function c(){ alert("Hello C"); c()}, 3000);
```

After getting all the functions executed I want the below function d() to get executed

```
function d(){
console.log('hello D')
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other)

Comment: @JeremyThille Nope, Its different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this like

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function a(){ alert("Hello A"); resolve();}, 3000);
})

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function b(){ alert("Hello B"); resolve();}, 3000);
})

var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function c(){ alert("Hello C"); resolve();}, 3000);
})

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function() {
  function d(){
     console.log('hello D') 
  }
  d(); 
});
```

Comment: damn, same answer, 10 seconds apart

Comment: @JeremyThille beat you :D

Comment: Let's say that you provided the ES5 solution and I provided the ES6 one :)

Comment: Yeah!! true that

Comment: Have you checked, you are calling the same function inside?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all` to do that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```js
const a = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => setTimeout( () => {
     console.log("a is finished");
     resolve()
    }, 3000) ),
   b = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => setTimeout( () => {
     console.log("b is finished");
     resolve()
    }, 1000) ),
   c =  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => setTimeout( () => {
     console.log("c is finished");
     resolve()
    }, 2000) )

const d = () => console.log('hello D')

Promise.all( [a,b,c] ).then(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some global variable/object to save state of executed each function and check at the end if you can start d function. Example:

```js
// you probably need some global variable/object
oCheckedFunctions = { a:false, b:false, c:false };
function d(){
 alert('hello D')
}
function a(){ 
 alert("Hello A"); 
 oCheckedFunctions.a = true;
 checkAndTryForD();
}
function b(){ 
 alert("Hello B"); 
 oCheckedFunctions.b = true;
 checkAndTryForD();
}
function c(){ 
 alert("Hello C"); 
 oCheckedFunctions.c = true;
 checkAndTryForD();
}

function checkAndTryForD() {
 if (oCheckedFunctions.a && oCheckedFunctions.b && oCheckedFunctions.c) {
  d();
 }
}

// your functions
setTimeout(a, 3000);
setTimeout(b, 3000);
setTimeout(c, 3000);
```

Comment: Granted, this works, but there are more elegant ways to do it.

Comment: ... and async/await :) https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

Answer (score 1):

Just define a promising timer once:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

So you can do:

```
 const log = v => _ => console.log(v);

 Promise.all([
  timer(3000).then(log("a")),
  timer(3000).then(log("b"))
 ]).then(log("c"));
```